# Bolt 4.x empty sidebar in the dashboard

Tags: symfony, content-management-system, dashboard, bolt

I rencently tried to upgrade my website from Bolt 4.1 to 4.2 to 5.0, without any success. My folder is under git, but unfortunately, while reverting all the files to its original state (v4.1), my website is not acting normal.

The frontend is working fine, but in the dashboard (.../bolt), **the side menu is totally empty**. The central view shows the list of my contents, and on the right some messages from Bolt.

Does anyone has any idea how to solve this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue recently, I found the solution. The [file system permissions](https://docs.boltcms.io/5.0/installation/permissions) was not set correctly after a checkout of the git repository (folders permissions may have been lost in the process).

By executing the following command, it solved the issue:

```
chmod -R 777 config/ public/files/ public/theme/ public/thumbs/ var/
```

I also posted the solution here:
https://github.com/bolt/core/discussions/2318#discussioncomment-3985748